# Why am i getting blank output after writing this filehandling code in c++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have made a tester class where I take questions from a question pool text file and put random questions from there to a docx file. I want to know why my code is giving me blank output in the docx file.
my random function is working fine. I am selecting two two questions from three questions file.
Here is my code - `

```
void test()
{
  string line;
  fstream question1("questiondesc.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
  fstream testgen("GeneratedTest.docx",ios::trunc | ios::in | ios::out);
  testgen.open("GeneratedTest.docx");
  if(!question1.is_open())
  {
    question1.open("questiondesc.txt");
  }
  int i,num; 
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    num = random(1,12);
    for(int i =1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        getline(question1,line);
    }
    question1.clear();
    question1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    testgen<<line<<endl;
  }
  question1.close();
  ifstream question2("questionmcq.txt");
  if(!question2.is_open())
  {
    question2.open("questionmcq.txt");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    num = random(1,26);
    while(num%2==0)
    { 
    num = random(1,26);
    }
    for(int i =1;i<=num;i++)
    {
      getline(question2,line);
    }
    testgen<<line<<endl;
    getline(question2,line);
    testgen<<line<<endl;
    question2.clear();
    question2.seekg(0, ios::beg);
  }
  question2.close();
  ifstream question3("questionanalytical.txt");
  if(!question3.is_open())
  {
    question3.open("questionanalytical.txt");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    num = random(1,12);
    for(int i =1;i<=num;i++)
    {
      getline(question3,line);
    }
    question3.clear();
    question3.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    testgen<<line<<endl;
  }
  question3.close();
  testgen.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `random`? What is the content of `questiondesc.txt` and `questionmcq.txt`? What is the expected output and why the format is docx (apart from the fact that it is not supposed to be blanc)? In this form it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Why are you opening testgen twice and not checking if it worked? Why are you trying twice in a row to open the question files? (Btw a `.docx` file is not a plain text file.)

Comment: Writing text to `docx` will produce a broken file.

Comment: There's no need to try an open files twice. If a file open didn't work the first time it isn't going to work the second. The code has the look of code that was close to working but has got worse as you tried to fix the errors.

Comment: Also decide whether a file is for inout or output, don't try to open file for both input and output (unless that's what you really want to do).

Comment: If a file fails to open, the most likely reason (I would say 99.9% of the time on this forum) is that the program is looking for the file in a different place to where the programmer expected.

Comment: The open fails not only, because the file is not in the expected location, here it fails definiteley with the given combination of flags.

Comment: random is a function i created for generating random numbers. questiondesc.txt and questionmcq.txt are files i created in the same folder which contains some question line-wise. expected output is that random question gets selected from these files and get into docx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your code. I will show them as a comment in the below listing. Additionally I will show (onw of many, and maybe not the best ) solutions for your problem.

You should break down your problem into smaller pieces and design more functions. Then, life will be easier.

Additionally. You´should write comments. If you write comments, then you will detect the problems by yourself.

Your code with my remarks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

using namespace std;  // NO NEVER USE

int random(int from, int to) {
    std::random_device                  random_device;
    std::mt19937                        generator(random_device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distribution(from, to);
    return distribution(generator);
}

void test()
{
    string line;    // Line is not initialized an not needed here. Pollutes namespace
    fstream question1("questiondesc.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);  // Opening a file with these flags will fail. Use ifstream
    fstream testgen("GeneratedTest.docx", ios::trunc | ios::in | ios::out);// Opening a file with these flags will fail. Use ofstream
    testgen.open("GeneratedTest.docx"); // File was alread opened and failed. Reopening will not work. It failed alread
    if (!question1.is_open()) // Use if "(!question1)" instead. There could be also other error bits
    {   // Always check the status of any IO operation
        question1.open("questiondesc.txt"); // Will never work. Failer already
    }
    int i, num; // Variable not initialized and not needed here. Name space pollution
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        num = random(1, 12); // This function was not defined. I redefined it
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)  // i=1 and i<= reaaly) not i=0 and i<num?
        {
            getline(question1, line);   // Always check status of any IO function
        }
        question1.clear();
        question1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        testgen << line << endl;
    }
    question1.close(); // The destructor of the fstream will close the file for you

    ifstream question2("questionmcq.txt");  // Now you open the file as ifstream
    if (!question2.is_open())  // Do check for all possible flags.: If (!question2)
    {
        question2.open("questionmcq.txt");  // Will not work, if it failed in the first time
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   // So 2 times
        num = random(1, 26);
        while (num % 2 == 0) // If numbers are equal
        {
            num = random(1, 26); // Get an odd number
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) // Usually from 0 to <num
        {
            getline(question2, line);
        }
        testgen << line << endl;
        getline(question2, line);
        testgen << line << endl;
        question2.clear();
        question2.seekg(0, ios::beg);
}
    question2.close();   // No need to close. Destructor will do it for you
    ifstream question3("questionanalytical.txt");    // Now you open the file as ifstream
    if (!question3.is_open())  // Wrong check. Check for all flags
    {
        question3.open("questionanalytical.txt"); // Will not help in case of failure
    }
    // Now this is the 3rd time with the same code. So, put it into a function
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        num = random(1, 12);
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            getline(question3, line);
        }
        question3.clear();
        question3.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        testgen << line << endl;
    }
    question3.close();
    testgen.close();
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

And here one possible solution. With functions to handler similar parts of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

// From the internet: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device
int random(int from, int to) {
    std::random_device                  random_device;
    std::mt19937                        generator(random_device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distribution(from, to);
    return distribution(generator);
}

std::string readNthLineFromFile(std::ifstream& ifs, int n) {

    // Reset file to the beginning
    ifs.clear();
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Default return string in case of error
    std::string result{ "\n*** Error while reading a line from the source file\n" };

    // If getline fails or ifs is in fail state, the string will be default
    for (; std::getline(ifs, result) && (n != 0); n--);

    // Give back the desired line
    return result;
}

void generateQuestion(std::ifstream& sourceFileStream, std::ofstream& destinationFileStream, int n, const bool twoLines = false) {

    // We want to prevent readin the same question again
    int oldLineNumber = 0;
    // For whatever reason, do this 2 times. 
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < 2; ++i) {



        // If we want to read 2 consecutive lines, then we should not come up with the last kine in the file
        if (twoLines & (n > 1)) --n;

        // Get a random line number. But no duplicates in the 2 loops
        int lineNumber{};
        do {
            lineNumber = random(1, n);
        } while (lineNumber == oldLineNumber);

        // For the next loop execution
        oldLineNumber = lineNumber;

        // Read the random line
        std::string line{ readNthLineFromFile(sourceFileStream, lineNumber) };

        // And write it to the destination file
        destinationFileStream << line << "\n";

        // If we want to read to lines in a row
        if (twoLines) {
            // Read next line
            line = readNthLineFromFile(sourceFileStream, ++lineNumber);

            // And write it to the destination file
            destinationFileStream << line << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    const std::string destinationFilename{ "generatedTest.txt" };
    const std::string questions1Filename{ "questiondesc.txt" };
    const std::string questions2Filename{ "questionmcq.txt" };
    const std::string questions3Filename{ "questionanalytical.txt" };

    // Here we store the filenames and if one or 2 lines shall be read
    std::vector<std::tuple<const std::string, const size_t, const bool>> source{
        { questions1Filename, 12U, false },
        { questions2Filename, 26U, true },
        { questions3Filename, 12U, false }
    };
    // Open the destination file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ofstream destinationFileStream(destinationFilename); destinationFileStream) {

        // Now open the first source file and generate the questions
        for (const std::tuple<const std::string, const size_t, const bool>& t : source) {

            // Open source file and check, if it could be opened 
            if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(std::get<0>(t)); sourceFileStream) {

                generateQuestion(sourceFileStream, destinationFileStream, std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t));
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Could not open source file '" << std::get<0>(t) << "'\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open destination file '" << destinationFilename << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to do it with the help of your remarks only by just modifying it.  I am new to file handling so I was not sure about it.